# How to filter one observable with another observable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, reactive-programming, reactive

With https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx,

I have two observables A and B.

I want A to be filtered by B. [Sample](http://rxmarbles.com/#sample) seems like what I want but the negative of it.

```
IObservable<long> A = Observable.EveryUpdate();            
IObservable<Collider2D> B = this.OnTriggerEnter2DAsObservable()
                .Where( x => x.gameObject.tag == "Wall");
```

I want some kind of Pseudo code like that:

```
A.filterBy(B)
 .Subscribe(x => Debug.Log(x)); //executed only when B is not streaming
```

(Update1)
Here is actual code. I am trying to cancel out input stream with colliding stream.

```
    var isCollidingWithWall = this.OnTriggerEnter2DAsObservable()
        .Where(collider => collider.gameObject.tag == "Wall");

    Func<long, float> displaceCalculate = (_) => this.Speed * Time.deltaTime;

    var moveLeft = Observable.EveryUpdate()
        .Where(_ => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow));
    var moveRight = Observable.EveryUpdate()
        .Where(_ => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow));

    var movement1 = moveLeft
        .Select(displaceCalculate)
        .Select(f => -f);

    var movement2 = moveRight
        .Select(displaceCalculate);

    movement2
        .Merge(movement1)
        .Subscribe(f =>
        {
            this.transform.position = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x + f, this.transform.position.y);
        });
```

I think I might be going in wrong direction.

Comment: Maybe it is not obvious that I am using UniRx? https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx

Comment: What does "executed only when B is not streaming" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to only combine operators.

The two streams are not synchronized. 
When the OnNext message comes from stream B, how long shut off stream A?
Next stream B message? or Next stream A?

If you want to stop it only one frame, how about this?

```
void Start()
{
    var isCollisionEntered = false;

    this.OnCollisionEnter2DAsObservable()
        .Where(x => x.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        .Subscribe(_ => isCollisionEntered = true);

    this.LateUpdateAsObservable()
        .Where(_ => isCollisionEntered)
        .Subscribe(_ => isCollisionEntered = false);

    this.UpdateAsObservable()
        .Where(_ => !isCollisionEntered)
        .Subscribe(_ => Debug.Log("Do here"));
}
```

And, I don't recommend `Observable.EveryUpdate` .It is necessary to manage lifetime.

I recommend using `this.UpdateAsObservable` (UniRx.Triggers) instead.
It automatically publishes `OnCompleted` message on the gameobject destroyed.

Comment: I am trying to do it purely with streams. I want zero booleans.

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov - What do you mean by "purely with streams"?

Comment: I do not want to have any kind of state. Boolean values are state. I want everything to be derived from events and input.

Comment: I think it is too difficult to make only purely with streams.

Comment: Another way is to create an operator by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with another way.

```
    var streamB = this.OnTriggerEnter2DAsObservable().AsUnitObservable();

    this.UpdateAsObservable()
        .TakeUntil(streamB)
        .RepeatUntilDestroy(this)
        .Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            Debug.Log(Time.frameCount);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more context about the actual game behavior you are trying to implement?

My guess would be that there is some other approach to what you are trying to do, without having to rely on `EveryUpdate` (e.g. by using `OnTriggerStay` and/or `OnTriggerExit`).

Just giving a guess to what you mean by "negative" of the sample operator: you might want to have a look at [pausable](http://rxmarbles.com/#pausable). You'd have to generate the proper boolean values though, and how to do that really depends on what game behavior you are actually trying to implement here.

Comment: I cannot find pausable at UniRx. :(

Comment: Maybe I can implement it myself somehow? I will research it when I get the time.